# Why am I getting a ORA-44737 Parameter does not exist when setting the MAX_DUMP_FILE_SIZE parameter on Oracle 18c?

Tags: oracle, trace, oracle18c

Here is my code, pretty straight forward, but it wont work. Thank you all!

```
begin
    -- to set the max dump file size for a given session
    sys.dbms_system.set_int_param_in_session(
        217,
        36575,
        'MAX_DUMP_FILE_SIZE',
        1073741824
    );
end;
```

It generates:

```
ORA-44737: Parameter MAX_DUMP_FILE_SIZE did not exist.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYSTEM", line 122
ORA-06512: at line 3
```

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that the code is straight-forward, since DBMS_SYSTEM is an undocumented package.  Is there a reason why you're not using the documented `alter session set max_dump_file_size = 1073741824;` instead?

Comment: How can I limit this particular user's dump size using alter session? Thank you!

Comment: @AlexPoole this alters variables for my session, not for a different user's session.

Comment: @AlexPoole, you can alter another user's session. I think that's what set_init_param_in_session does. It works on my Oracle 11 server but not my Oracle 18 server. Yes, this is part of a procedure that is controlled via Apex. It sets the users parameters, the user then does things on the DB and then when the actions are done, the Apex app can shut off tracing for that session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that 18c is just reporting an error that 11g used to silently ignore; namely that the parameter name doesn't exist, or at least isn't the right type for the procedure. In 11g this didn't error, but also didn't do anything. As a normal user:

```
select name, type, display_value
from v$parameter
where name in ('max_dump_file_size', 'sort_area_size');

NAME                                 TYPE DISPLAY_VALUE
------------------------------ ---------- ------------------------------
sort_area_size                          3 65536
max_dump_file_size                      2 unlimited
```

As SYS after identifying that session:

```
begin
    sys.dbms_system.set_int_param_in_session(
        209,
        34295,
        'MAX_DUMP_FILE_SIZE',
        123456
    );
    sys.dbms_system.set_int_param_in_session(
        209,
        34295,
        'SORT_AREA_SIZE',
        123456
    );
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

In the original user's session:

```
select name, type, display_value
from v$parameter
where name in ('max_dump_file_size', 'sort_area_size');

NAME                                 TYPE DISPLAY_VALUE
------------------------------ ---------- ------------------------------
sort_area_size                          3 123456
max_dump_file_size                      2 unlimited
```

The `sort_area_size` change has taken effect. The `max_dump_file_size` has not - but it didn't report that, or complain. In fact you can pass anything you like as the parameter name and it will still silently ignore it.

In 18c it is no longer silent, so you see the ORA-44737 error.

The reason it complains, it seems, comes down to the name of the procedure - `set_int_param_in_session` - and the parameter type. It works for `sort_area_size` because [that is an integer parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/SORT_AREA_SIZE.html); but `max_dump_file_size` [is a string parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/MAX_DUMP_FILE_SIZE.html). It might be more helpful if the error said "Parameter MAX_DUMP_FILE_SIZE did not exist or was the wrong type", but you can't have everything.

You happen to be trying to pass it an integer value, but you might not be - and there's no way to pass `'UNLIMITED'` as a number argument. In this case it could, perhaps, have been written allow the numeric values anyway - but then you would have no way to reset it, which would be problematic.

Unfortunately there isn't an equivalent `set_str_param_in_session` procedure, and as it's an undocumented and unsupported package it's unlikely you'd get very far asking Oracle to add one.

I don't think there's any way to do what you're attempting from another session.

I'm not aware of any way to apply this via a profile or resource manager either. With some advance planning you could potentially have a way to tell Apex (e.g. via a parameter somewhere) to set this itself, but that sounds like a lot of work. It might be simpler to use a logon trigger to always set this (for some users, or in a role, perhaps) via an `alter session` call, so you don't have to think about it when starting a trace.

Comment: You're awesome! Yup, I also discovered this was ever actually working due to the silent ignore. I'm just using 'ALTER SYSTEM SET MAX_DUMP_FILE_SIZE = 123' and then changing it back when done. Thank you for this excellent post!